# Twitter bootstrap accordion not working with Sammy.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sammy.js, single-page-application

I am trying to use twitter accordion in single page app but it has conflict with sammy.js

```
<a class="ac-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ac2" href="#collapseOne">Company</a>
```

When I try to collapse it change the url.  I have ignore the route in sammy.js but it did not work.  Is there other method of this using jquery or ignore the route in sammy.js ?

```
 this.get(/\#collapse(.*)/, function (cx, match) {
    ????
 });
```