# Ignore section reference with Sammy.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, durandal, sammy.js

[Twitter bootstrap accordion not working with Sammy.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284022/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-not-working-with-sammy-js)

Is a similar question but was never answered.

I am creating an affixed Twitter Bootstrap side nav-list and using has based href's but when I click on them Sammy is trying to catch the routes.  Since I am dynamically creating the Id's and href's I can prevent them from ever matching an existing route but it constantly hits the console with errors.  I am sure in production they won't show up but is there anything that can be done to prevent this?

```
        <ul class="nav nav-list affix">
            <!-- ko foreach: sections -->
                <li class="nav-header"><span data-bind="text: navDesc"></span></li>
                    <!-- ko foreach: paragraphs -->
                    <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: '#' + navProp() }"><span data-bind="text: navDesc"></span> <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                    <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
```

I know this will be fixed in the next version of Durandal but just checking any other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durandal 1.2 provides a `guardRoute` method, which will allow you to intercept the call before it reaches sammy.

Check out [How to handle / ignore a bad route with durandal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089694/example-use-of-durandals-guardroute) for more information.

Comment: Rainer I am sure this is headed down the right path but I don't know the name of the route to guard before activate my shell.js as my routes are dynamically created based off an entities property, can you be a bit more descriptive of how this would work?  Are you saying set a predecessor like /#/#guarded(and then the nav id?)

Comment: Not sure if I can be more specific as it's your app ;-). Looking at the provided example how to you make sure that navProp() doesn't interfere with any manually routes at the moment? Adding a prefix for all routes that should be ignored seems to be a viable options.

Comment: Rainer after two weeks of trying to get this to work I don't think this is the solution.  Router is catching everything j do as a bad route

Comment: sorry to hear. Durandal 2.0 is coming closer and I've just updated https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0. This is still using alpha bits, but it looks as if the new router is already pretty stable.